# PubNub framework in Apple Watch

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, pubnub

I have been trying to manually import the PubNub Framework into my Apple Watch app. There are a lot of dependencies and frameworks that are used by PubNub that are not available on the watch (i.e. SystemConfiguration, CFNetworking, etc.). Is Apple Watch supported by PubNub? How do I get it to nicely import into my Apple Watch app?

Comment: I have alerted the PubNub engineer team to review this.

Comment: We'll help you via our support center, and then reply-all back here with the general solution for all once we've dug in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a few modifications needs to be made. Replacing UIKit with WatchKit replacements:

#### TLDR:

- Replace `UIDevice` with `WKInterfaceDevice` replacements
- Replace `[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForDevice]` with UUID stored in `NSUserDefaults`
- Replace `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` with `NSExtensionHostWillEnterForegroundNotification` and `NSExtensionHostDidEnterBackgroundNotification`
- Remove GZIP references

#### Detailed Explanation By File:

`PNConfiguration.m`:

```
    - (NSString *)uniqueDeviceIdentifier {
#if TARGET_OS_WATCH
        NSString *key = @"PNUserDefaultsUUIDKey";
        NSString *uuid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:key];
        if (!uuid) {
            uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:uuid forKey:key];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
        return uuid;
#elif __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
        return [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
#elif __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
        return ([self serialNumber]?: [self macAddress]);
#endif
    }
```

`PNNetwork.m`:

```
    - (NSDictionary *)defaultHeaders {
        NSString *device = @"iPhone";
        NSString *osVersion = @"2.0";
#if TARGET_OS_WATCH
        osVersion = [[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
        device = [[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] model];
#elif __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
        device = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
        osVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
#elif __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
        NSOperatingSystemVersion version = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo]operatingSystemVersion];
        NSMutableString *osVersion = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",
                              @(version.majorVersion), @(version.minorVersion)];
        if (version.patchVersion > 0) {

            [osVersion appendFormat:@".%@", @(version.patchVersion)];
    }
#endif
        NSString *userAgent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"iPhone; CPU %@ OS %@ Version",
                       device, osVersion];

         return @{@"Accept":@"*/*", @"Accept-Encoding":@"gzip,deflate", @"User-Agent":userAgent,
         @"Connection":@"keep-alive"};
    }
```

`PubNub+Core.m`:

```
    - (instancetype)initWithConfiguration:(PNConfiguration *)configuration
                    callbackQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)callbackQueue {

// Check whether initialization has been successful or not
        if ((self = [super init])) {
#if DEBUG
            [PNLog dumpToFile:YES];
#else
            [PNLog dumpToFile:NO];
#endif

            DDLogClientInfo([[self class] ddLogLevel], @"<PubNub> PubNub SDK %@ (%@)",
                    kPNLibraryVersion, kPNCommit);

            _configuration = [configuration copy];
            _callbackQueue = callbackQueue;
            [self prepareNetworkManagers];

            _subscriberManager = [PNSubscriber subscriberForClient:self];
            _clientStateManager = [PNClientState stateForClient:self];
            _listenersManager = [PNStateListener stateListenerForClient:self];
            _heartbeatManager = [PNHeartbeat heartbeatForClient:self];
            [self addListener:self];
            [self prepareReachability];
#if TARGET_OS_WATCH
            NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
            [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleContextTransition:)
                               name:NSExtensionHostWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
            [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleContextTransition:)
                               name:NSExtensionHostDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
#elif __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
            NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
            [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleContextTransition:)
                               name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
            [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleContextTransition:)
                               name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
#elif __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
            NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notifiertionCenter];
            [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleContextTransition:)
                               name:NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification object:nil];
            [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleContextTransition:)
                               name:NSWorkspaceSessionDidResignActiveNotification object:nil];
            [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleContextTransition:)
                               name:NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification object:nil];
            [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleContextTransition:)
                               name:NSWorkspaceSessionDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
#endif
        }

        return self;
    }
```

`PubNub+Core.m`:

```
    - (void)handleContextTransition:(NSNotification *)notification {
#if TARGET_OS_WATCH
        if ([notification.name isEqualToString:NSExtensionHostDidEnterBackgroundNotification]) {

            DDLogClientInfo([[self class] ddLogLevel], @"<PubNub> Did enter background execution context.");
        }
        else if ([notification.name isEqualToString:NSExtensionHostWillEnterForegroundNotification]) {

            DDLogClientInfo([[self class] ddLogLevel], @"<PubNub> Will enter foreground execution context.");
        }
#elif __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
        if ([notification.name isEqualToString:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification]) {

            DDLogClientInfo([[self class] ddLogLevel], @"<PubNub> Did enter background execution context.");
        }
        else if ([notification.name isEqualToString:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification]) {

            DDLogClientInfo([[self class] ddLogLevel], @"<PubNub> Will enter foreground execution context.");
        }
#elif __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
        if ([notification.name isEqualToString:NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification] ||
        [notification.name isEqualToString:NSWorkspaceSessionDidResignActiveNotification]) {

            DDLogClientInfo([[self class] ddLogLevel], @"<PubNub> Workspace became inactive.");
        }
        else if ([notification.name isEqualToString:NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification] ||
             [notification.name isEqualToString:NSWorkspaceSessionDidBecomeActiveNotification]) {

            DDLogClientInfo([[self class] ddLogLevel], @"<PubNub> Workspace became active.");
        }
#endif
    }
```

`PubNub+Core.m`:

```
    - (void)dealloc {
#if TARGET_OS_WATCH
        NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:NSExtensionHostWillEnterForegroundNotification
                            object:nil];
        [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:NSExtensionHostDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                            object:nil];
#elif __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
        NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                            object:nil];
        [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                            object:nil];
#elif __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
        NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];
        [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification object:nil];
        [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:NSWorkspaceSessionDidResignActiveNotification
                            object:nil];
        [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification object:nil];
        [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:NSWorkspaceSessionDidBecomeActiveNotification
                            object:nil];
#endif
    }
```

`PubNub+Publish.m`: where PNGZIP is used

```
    NSData *publishData = nil;
    if (compressed) {
#if !TARGET_OS_WATCH
        NSData *messageData = [messageForPublish dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSData *compressedBody = [PNGZIP GZIPDeflatedData:messageData];
        publishData = (compressedBody?: [@"" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
#else
        NSLog(@"Tried to compress, but GZip is not available");
#endif
    }
```